# Are query execution plans stored anywhere in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, explain

I am trying to figure out if PostgreSQL query execution plans are stored somewhere (possibly as complimentary to `pg_stat_statements` and `pg_prepared_statements`) in a way they are available for longer than the duration of the session. I understand that `PREPARE` does cache a sql statement in `pg_prepared_statements`, though the plan itself does not seem to be available in any view as far as I can tell.

I am not sure if there is a doc explaining the life cycle of a query plan for PostgreSQL but from what it sounds in the [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/using-explain.html) documentation, PostgreSQL does not cache query plans at all. Is this accurate?

Thanks!

Comment: you can save plan for every query to logs with `auto_explain`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PostgreSQL has no shared storage for execution plans, so they cannot be reused across database sessions.

There are two ways to cache an execution plan within a session:

1. Use prepared statements with the SQL statements `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`. The plan will be cached for the life time of the prepared statement, usually until your session ends.
2. Use PL/pgSQL functions. The plans for all static SQL statements (that is, statements that are *not* run with `EXECUTE`) in such a function will be cached for the session life time.

Other than that, execution plans are not cached in PostgreSQL.